# Markdown Live Preview Editor?

Tags: macos, textmate, markdown, word-processing, wysiwyg

I am currently using `Textmate` to create Markdown documents, but it requires me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> everytime I want to 'update' the Markdown output window. Essentially I am using it like a  word processor.

Is there a Markdown editor for Mac OS X which supports wysiwig/live update of the content? Perhaps Textmate already does this?

Comment: Searching the same for Linux, still this question is very useful (there are some portable programs listed here)

Comment: There are several editors with inline previewing/wysiwyg capabilities here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/markdown-editor-for-windows-with-inbuilt-live-viewer-inside-the-editor-itself

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to use TextMate, change your file's language association to 'HTML'. In the Preview window there is a drawer that offers the option pipe the text through 'Markdown.pl'. (See screenshot).

[image: Markdown]

The alternative I use for Makrdown is not an officially released app but personally I use [markdownlive](http://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive) by Jonathan 'Wolf' Rentzsch. It's open source available on GitHub and will require you to compile it using Xcode. It also allows you to copy the Generated HTML (what I like to use it for quite a bit).

Comment: I tried markdownlive. It works, but like you said its in development and is quite primitive in the way of syntax colouring. I will try you other method soon.

Comment: you do not have to set your file type to html. if you use the markdown bundle, you just need to remove the key equivalent activation of preview in the bundle settings. then textmate's show web preview in the window menu will give you a live preview.

Comment: What about multimarkdown?

Comment: You don't have to build MarkdownLive yourself: https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive/downloads

Comment: +1 For @yanokwa's comment. I particularly like this fork of the markdown plugin, which nicely preserves things like indentation for unordered lists: https://github.com/fletcher/markdown.tmbundle

Answer (score 62):

There is also "Mou", a live editor for Mac OS X (Lion). It's still in beta, but works great! http://mouapp.com/

> When current available Markdown editors are almost all for general writers, Mou is different: It's for web developers. Syntax highlighting, live preview, fullscreen mode, auto save, powerful actions, auto pair, incremental search, custom themes, HTML export, enhanced CJK characters support.

[image]

Comment: Mou looks great, but requires Lion.

Answer (score 28):

Mac only, [Marked](http://markedapp.com/) provides markdown and multi-markdown preview for any text editor. The preview is updated when you save the text file.

[image: Marked screenshot]

---

[MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) is for Windows, but provides live preview.

[image: MarkdownPad screenshot]

---

ReText is available for other platforms and offers a live preview of rendered Markdown:

> [ReText](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/home/ReText/) is a simple text editor for Markdown syntax. It is written in Python using Qt libraries, able to run on any platforms (Linux and BSD are officially supported)

[image: ReText screenshot]

Although not officially supported, there are [Windows installation instructions](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/wiki/Windows%20Install%20of%20ReText/) as well; however, I had to make a few modifications to get them to work (the complete set with my corrections is shown below):

#### Installation

1. Install [Python27](http://sourceforge.net/nf/redirect/?path=http%3A//www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/python-2.7.1.msi)
2. Install PyQT precompiled for <s>PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.3-1.exe</s> [PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.4-1.exe](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.4-1.exe)
3. Install easy_install [setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe](http://sourceforge.net/nf/redirect/?path=http%3A//pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe%23md5%3D57e1e64f6b7c7f1d2eddfc9746bbaf20)
4. Update your My Computer's Environmental Variables. Click `Start`, right-click `My Computer` and select `Properties`, select the `Advanced` tab, then click `Environment Variables`.
5. Under `System Variables`, click `New`. Under variable name enter `PYTHONPATH`. Under `Variable value` enter `C:\Python27\Lib\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\`
6. Select the System Variable `PATH` click `Edit`. Update the PATH `variable value` by adding `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin;` to the front of the existing entries so that it reads like `PATH=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin;...`
7. Install additional Python libraries. Select `Start` then `Run`, type `cmd` then `cd \python27\scripts`. Enter:

   - `easy_install Pygments`
   - `easy_install ElementTree`
   - `easy_install Markdown`
   - `easy_install gdata`
8. Download and unpack current ReText (ATM [0.8.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/retext/files/ReText-beta/ReText_0.8.1.tar.gz/download))
9. Download and unpack [ReText icons](http://sourceforge.net/projects/retext/files/Icons/ReText_icons_r2.tar.gz/download)
10. Place the unpacked icons into the ReText\icons folder
11. Navigate to the retext.py file (probably at `c:\retext`). Right-click drag-and-drop retext.py and select `Create shortcuts here`.
12. Right-click on the shortcut to adjust the properties.
13. Change `target` to `"C:\Python27\python.exe" retext.py` and `Run` to `minimized`.
14. Change the icon (which will require you to make an `.ico` file from one of the `.png` files unzipped above into the `ReText/icons` directory, which can be done [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-ico-file-in-30-seconds/)
15. Change the shortcut name on the general tab if desired.

Comment: For those who want to get Marked (which I really can recommend) and still have Snow Leopard (10.6), there is a free Snow Leopard only download available through the FAQ (https://marked.tenderapp.com/kb/documentation/frequently-asked-questions): http://assets.markedapp.com/MarkedSL.zip

Comment: better to list each of these as separate answers

Answer (score 19):

[MarkdownLive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive) does exactly what you want, free and open source.

Download the release through GitHub, or version 1.7.1 from [here](https://github.com/downloads/rentzsch/markdownlive/MarkdownLive-1.7.1.zip).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[BBEdit](http://barebones.com/products/bbedit/) does this out of the box: set the current document type to be Markdown, open Preview in BBEdit, and type away. The preview window auto-updates, showing your text just the way you want it.

See page 277 of the [BBEdit User Manual](http://pine.barebones.com/manual/BBEdit_9_User_Manual.pdf) for details.

Comment: Ugh! I like BBEdit for several reasons, but characterizing its ability to handle Markdown in a *user-friendly* way is a *stretch*. And BTW, your link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs markdown mode gives you a live preview as you write, and also a full HTML/Browser preview with `C-c` `C-p`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### [nvALT - Notational Velocity Fork](http://brettterpstra.com/project/nvalt/)

[image: nvalt]

Comment: Tried it, but it could not open the md file...

Answer (score 3):

[vim-instant-markdown](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) is a vim plugin that shows near-instant updates in your system default web browser.  It even works in MacVim, though I had to fiddle with $PATH a little.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you did to your $PATH?

Answer (score 2):

The recently revived [Smultron](http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/) can do that as well without pressing any keys:

1. Set the "Preview Parser" to "Markdown" in the advanced preferences under "Really Advanced".
2. Then open the preview window with "Tools" / "Preview". Voilà.

Answer (score 2):

[Texts](http://www.texts.io/) for Mac OS X and Windows.

[image: Texts Screenshot]

Comment: **Warning**: the website buries the information that Texts is **not free**. You can use it only for 30 days before you must [purchase a license](http://www.texts.io/purchase/).

Answer (score 1):

An old, but still relevant, question. All the answers appear to be 8-10 years old, but I believe that [Typora](https://typora.io/) is the answer as of today.

AFAIK, there's nothing quite like it: As you type your *markdown* in the editor, Typora displays the "code". Once you've completed an actively-edited passage, Typora collapses it as *rendered* text.

It's also free ($) during its beta release phase.

Comment: Apparently you are correct - thanks for the update. I don't even recall now how I concluded it was open source... perhaps something has changed? "Free during beta" has always been the case, but it's been beta for so long, I wondered if this was to become its perpetual state. But it appears now that beta will end "soon".

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio Code (vscode) supports it out of the box**

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows users can use Resophnotes to write their text in Markdown and use the "HTML" icon to preview the marked up text then export the html formatted text.

http://www.resoph.com/ResophNotes/Welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

I might as well a link to my SU question - where I looked for the same, just PHP/JavaScript based (that can run on a locally installed server):

[Markdown "single page" PHP web application with live preview? [closed] - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/429157/markdown-single-page-php-web-application-with-live-preview)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there's the beautiful [MarkText](https://github.com/marktext/marktext) among others.