# Markdown "single page" PHP web application with live preview?

Tags: php, markdown

I would like to know if there is a PHP web application, such that

- When called with something like `http://example.com/index.php?inputfile=mymarkdownfile.txt`; it will open the file `mymarkdownfile.txt` at the same location as `index.php` on the webserver, and render it as Markdown (i.e., it will convert the Markdown to HTML and serve it)
- There will be an "edit" button, which opens a "live preview" Markdown editor (like on StackExchange/StackOverflow sites)
- When you're done editing and click on the "save" button, previous version is archived on server (saved as text file `mymarkdownfile-`timestamp`.txt`), and the changed version is saved as `mymarkdownfile.txt`.
- If you try to "open" a "nonexisting file" (*say, via `http://example.com/index.php?inputfile=nonexistant.txt`*), then the editor starts first; and the content typed there will be saved as `nonexistant.txt` (and `nonexistant-`timestamp`.txt`)

I just need this for server based note taking, and I don't really need local linking or anything like that; nor user authentication nor protection (I'd intend to use this on local network, so I wouldn't be worried about public exposure of "edit" button and vandalism).

I imagine it could be a PHP page, which uses:

- [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) library for the initial conversion to HTML when the page request is first read
- [pagedown - A JavaScript Markdown converter and editor](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) (*see also [Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135155/277826)*) for when the editor is active..

Anything like that out there?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: I was looking for **exactly this** a while ago. Didn't find it. Settled with [markdoc](http://markdoc.org/).

Comment: Cheers, @OliverSalzburg - thanks for the reference!

Comment: I also looked at [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com). And I use [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) for editing. Sadly not even close to what I (and you) originally wanted. But it works. History can be provided by VCS like [git](http://git-scm.com/) if the product doesn't have anything built in. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for those references too, @OliverSalzburg - since apparently there is nothing else, I put something together, please see [answer below](http://superuser.com/a/429236/39752). Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, given that I really needed something like this, I put together a small PHP script/application that does the above; called it the Single-page Markdown Web Editor (`spmdwe`); please see:

- http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/spmdwe/

[image]

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for building this. It's just what I was looking for (mainly for checking the rendering of markdown as I enter it). I presume it wouldn't be too much of a mission to adapt to load/save data to/from a tuple in a database instead of a file.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't sanitize input retrieved from `$_REQUEST[]` before outputting it directly. You should do something about that.

Comment: Based on this useful application, I developed a new one. It has a nicer interface and more functions like history, download file, mark a file as read-only and view and editing modes.
It is available here: http://www.spmdwe.tk/
The repository is available here: https://github.com/rigon/notes